# How to expose bin javascript files out of Angular Library

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library

I am creating a library, which exposes some bin scripts to the user, which he then can use in his build process. However I have truble with exposing such scripts to a `dist` package.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "bin": {
    "foobar": "./bin/custom-build.js"
  }
}
```

And a structure looks like this:

[image: Project structure]

When I run a build the `custom-build.js` is nowhere to be found in `dist` diresctory. My question is how do I expose such files?

Answer (score -1):

You should add them to `angular.json`.
They will be combined into `scripts.js` in `dist`.

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-project-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "scripts": [
              "path/to/your/lib1.js",
              "path/to/your/lib2.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

There is no option to copy file in Angular CLI.
You can archive that by using external tool e.g. bash script, gulp
https://gulpjs.com/

Then incorporate it into your `package.js`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build && gulp bundle"
  }
}
```

Comment: Angular library doesn't support build scripts

Comment: What is more I don't want them to be combined into scripts.js. I want each to be in a separate file so they are accessible using package.json bin functionality

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? There is no such option in Angular CLI.